# jQuery move div from position 1 to 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple divs (haveing same class names). I want to move the div (always same div, which has unique ID `#pos1`) to the div which has been clicked. So, for that purpose, I am using following code to find the position1 (of the div which I want to move) and pos2 (the div which is clicked).

However, I don't know know how can I move (animate etc) the div from one position to another. I will appriciate any help.

```
jQuery(".container").click(function() {

    var pos1 = jQuery("#pos1").position();
    alert(pos1.top + ', ' + pos1.left);

    var pos2 = jQuery(this).position();
    alert(pos2.top + ', ' + pos2.left);

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all make sure that all your `.container` divs are `position:absolute`

Then you can use the following `animate` function of jQuery:

```
$('.container').click(function(){
    var pos1 = $('#pos1').position();

    $(this).animate({ 'top': pos1.top + 'px', 'left': pos1.left + 'px'}, 200, function(){
        //end of animation.. if you want to add some code here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the divs should have `position :relative` or may be you can give your moving div a `position: absolute` for top and left to work properly.